# How do I quit vterm's command history searching and start editing the command line?

Tags: term

`vterm` can search the command history by sending `C-r` to terminal process, but the command line cannot be modified unless it is executed as it is once. In other words, the string to search keeps changing by my editing because I can't get out of searching state. Is there a way to quit searching to start editing? It doesn't seem to be `C-g`, it shows "Quit" in minibuffer as usual but the prompt "bck-i-search:"(from my terminal zsh) remains.

**Update:**

It was due to disabling these keys in `vterm-mode-map` itself that can be used to quit the prompt, by myself stupidly:

```lisp
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-a") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-b") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-e") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-f") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-n") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-p") nil)
```

These are originally bound to `vterm--self-insert` for passing raw input to terminal.
Because I still want to move around in `vterm` buffer in the same way as in normal buffer using normal keys for moving cursor,
is there a way to keep the keys quitable and movable, by detecting whether the cursor position is on the command line or not, after leaving the command line using `isearch` etc?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: exactly as you guessed, I can quit the prompt easily with any key for moving cursor under minimum settings. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll define a key only for quiting the prompt and use it for a while..

```lisp
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-q") #'vterm-send-C-e)
```

**Update:**
It's not very good, but I chose the easy way to prioritize the normal keybindings and change the prefix (using `vterm-send-*` for sending a specific key) for inline moving (also for quiting from the prompt) on the command line.

```lisp
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-a") nil) ;; disable to move around everywhere in the buffer by the key in global-map.
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-b") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-e") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-f") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-n") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-p") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-s") nil) ;; for isearch.
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "C-v") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-v") nil)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-a") 'vterm-send-C-a) ;; change the prefix key C to M for moving on the command line.
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-b") 'vterm-send-C-b)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-e") 'vterm-send-C-e)
(define-key vterm-mode-map (kbd "M-f") 'vterm-send-C-f)
```